# Values not saving to db in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a form to create a record in my rails4 application.  Unfortunately, when I submit the record, a new record is added to the database but all of the columns are empty.  I ran the rails console and added a location record via a hash (Location.new({...})) and this worked perfectly, so I know the controller and model work.

Can you see any issues with the view or any other parts of this code?  I have been trying to find the problem for hours but I am stuck.  This is very frustrating - please help!

**locations/new.html.haml**

```
render 'form'
```

**link to add a record**

```
= link_to 'Add Location', new_location_path
```

**routes**

```
resources :locations
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for (@location) do |f|
  .row  
    .large-6.columns
      = f.input :name
    .large-6.columns
      = f.input :address
    .large-6.columns
      Location Name
  .row
    .large-6.columns
      =f.input :state
  .row
    = f.button :submit
```

**locations_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(subject_params)
    if @location.save
      redirect_to @location
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def subject_params
      params.permit(:name, :address, :state)
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `subject_params` method in `LocationsController` as:

```
   def subject_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:name, :address, :state)
   end
```

In `Rails 4`, `Strong Parameters` were introduced. So, you need to permit the attributes explicitly that you would like to insert/update in database.

In your `params` hash,  `:name`, `:address` and `:state` would be stored as key-value pairs for `:location` key.

You missed the `require(:location)` call on params hash which is why your record was not getting saved with the passed attributes.

Comment: I never get the chance to answer a question when you're online =P

Comment: :) It happens with me also. This time I was lucky.

Comment: No problem, you deserve it !

Comment: @kirti - you have trouble answering a question when you're online, too?!  lol  :)

Comment: Excellent help - thank you very much!  I'll accept this answer in 4 mins when stack overflow allows me to.  It's amazing how you can overlook something for HOURS!  Thank you again!!

Comment: Why would it allow me to add the location record through the rails console?  I thought that was going through the rails stack before saving a record...

Comment: @wahwahsoserious Glad to help. You know what I meant back there. :)

Comment: Through rails console you are directly interacting with Model. You are not going via Controller.

Comment: I know what you meant - just had to give you a hard time!  Thanks again for your excellent help. :)